# What happens after we assign to a dereferenced pointer an another dereferenced pointer?

Tags: c++

I can't understand what happens after line `*p1=10`, what happens with `*p2` variable, and in the end how does `secondvalue` variable gets 20.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
  int * p1, * p2;

  p1 = &firstvalue;  
  p2 = &secondvalue; 
  *p1 = 10;          
  *p2 = *p1;         
  p1 = p2;          
  *p1 = 20;         
  
  cout << "firstvalue is " << firstvalue << '\n';
  cout << "secondvalue is " << secondvalue << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Output of command

```
firstvalue is 10
secondvalue is 20
```

I can't understand how the `secondvalue` variable gets a value of 20.

If we assigned `*p2=*p1` mustn't `secondvalue` variable get 10?

Comment: You set it to 20 here: `*p1 = 20;`.

Comment: The line `p1 = p2;` makes them both point to `secondvalue`. The line `*p1 = 20` changes `secondvalue` to 20

Comment: But, in above line *p2 got *p1, which is 10, isn't it works like from up to down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets see this step by step:

```
int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
```

This initializes two 4 byte integers.

```
---------------------------------------
|                 |                   |
|  firstvalue (5) |  secondvalue (15) |
|                 |                   |
---------------------------------------
```

2. Initializes int pointers and sets their values

```
int * p1, * p2;
p1 = &firstvalue;  
p2 = &secondvalue;
```

p1 now stores the address of firstvalue, and p2 stores the address of secondvalue

```
---------------------------------------
|           (*p1) |             (*p2) |
|  firstvalue (5) |  secondvalue (15) |
|                 |                   |
---------------------------------------
      p1                  p2
```

3. Now you assign 10 to *p1. What this does is that it modifies the value at the **memory address** which was stored in p1:

```
*p1 = 10;
```

```
---------------------------------------
|           (*p1) |             (*p2) |
| firstvalue (10) |  secondvalue (15) |
|             ^^  |                   |
---------------------------------------
      p1                  p2
```

4. Now you assign `*p1` to the memory address stored in `p2`. `*p1` dereferences the pointer `p1` and returns you the value it is pointing to.

```
*p2 = *p1;
```

```
---------------------------------------
|           (*p1) |             (*p2) |
| firstvalue (10) |  secondvalue (10) |
|                 |               ^^  |
---------------------------------------
      p1                  p2
```

5. Now you **change** the memory address p1 is pointing to. Now p1 and p2 points to the same variable

```
p1 = p2;
```

```
---------------------------------------
|                 |    (*p1) (*p2)    |
| firstvalue (10) |  secondvalue (10) |
|                 |                   |
---------------------------------------
                        p1  p2
```

6. Finally, you modify the value at the memory address stored by p1, (that is also p2).

```
*p1 = 20;
```

```
---------------------------------------
|                 |    (*p1) (*p2)    |
| firstvalue (10) |  secondvalue (20) |
|                 |               ^^  |
---------------------------------------
                        p1  p2
```

Comment: Very clear explanation. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
p1 = p2;
```

This doesn't copy the value pointers point to, just "address" the `p2` points to. Thus at this point both `p1` and `p2` point to the `secondvalue`, and changing either of them applies changes to the `secondvalue`

Answer (score 1):

> If we assigned *p2=*p1 mustn't secondvalue variable get 10?

It sure does. And if that was the last assignment, then that what would happen. But perhaps you've noticed that there are more assignments, that follow this one:

```
p1 = p2;
```

`p1` is now pointing to the same value that `p2` is pointing to. `p2` is pointing to `secondvalue`, so `p1` is now pointing to `secondvalue`, too.

```
*p1 = 20;
```

The value that `p1` points to gets assigned `20`. And that's how `secondvalue` gets assigned 20.

Comment: Thank you guys!!!! You have clarified my doubts, I have just started learning this topic, and it is a bit difficult. Thanks a lot to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, but when you `p1 = p2;` you make so p1 now stores the reference to second value, and in the line below you assing *p1 (this is secondvalue) to 20.

So in your code flow firstvalue is assigned to 10 on `*p1 = 10;` and secondvalue is assigned to 20 on `*p1 = 20;`

Answer (score 0):

So, **pointers** and **references** (and ***de*-referencing**, oh my!)

Alas, this is where vocabulary makes a difference, and people *love* this particular selection of vocabulary. So here it is, explained in all its glory.

### Values

A **value** is something that exists somewhere in memory (like a variable, though not necessarily). To be useful, we programmers like to give values both a **type** and a **name**.

```
int    x    = 74;
double pi   = 3.141592;
string name = "Hannah";
```

### References

A **direct reference** is an *alias*, another name, if you will, for a value.

```
int  x = 7;  // type:int, name:x, value:7
int& z = x;  // z = another name for x
z = 12;      // x = 12;
```

Using aliases is something we do in normal life.

- I call my father “**Dad**”.
- Dad’s friends call him “**Bill**”.
- My friends call him “**Mr. Greer**”.

Different names. Same person.

<sup>Now, some C++ purists will tell you these are just plain *references*. Well, yes... and no. Yes, as far as the C++ Language is concerned. No, as far as understanding things is concerned. Just remember that when talking to C++ people, the word “reference”, unless otherwise qualified with some adjective, *always* means *direct reference*, or *alias*.</sup>

### Pointers

Before C++ introduced “references” as part of the language abstraction, we had **indirect references** — also called *pointers*.

It is *indirect* because a pointer is not itself a reference. But you can *get* a reference from a pointer’s value by **dereferencing** it using the `*` operator.

The term is a bit wonky (because it looks like you are “un”-referencing it), but the opposite is true: you are taking that indirect reference (the pointer value) and effectively converting it into an (unnamed) *direct* reference, an *alias* for the “pointed-to” (or “referenced”) value.

```
int  x  = 7;
int* px = &x;  // type=(pointer to int)  name=“px”  value=(address of x)
*px = 12;      // (direct reference to x) = 12
```

In other words `px` is a pointer with an indirect reference to — i.e. address of — `x`.

Thus when we dereference `px` with the `*` operator, we transform the expression into a direct reference to `x` — at which point we have access to read or modify `x`’s value just as if we had `x` in hand to begin with.

<sup>I suspect the term “dereference” came about because we are “un”-*indirect* referencing a pointer value to obtain a direct reference, but all the people who created the term are dead now and I don’t know of any place they felt the need to explain it.</sup>

### WHAT YOU MEANT TO ASK

So, a *dereferenced* pointer is an alias for the target object. You want to know what happens if you *don’t* dereference the pointers, which would be:

##### “What happens if we assign an *un*-dereferenced pointer to another *un*-dereferenced pointer?”

... and *un*-dereferenced means *not* dereferenced, so you are basically asking:

##### What happens when we assign one pointer to another?

The answer at this point should not be a surprise: *the same thing that happens whenever we assign any variable’s value to another*.

```
int  x  = 7;
int* p1 = &x;  // p1 now “points to” x
int* p2 = p1;  // and now p2 also “points to” x
```

Remember, the ***value*** of a pointer is the address of another object in memory, and you can copy values around however you like.

```
*p2 = 42;  // x = The Answer
```